# Show that a subset W of a vector space V is a subspace of V if and only if span(W) = W

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-verification

Show that a subset W of a vector space V is a subspace of V if and only if span(W) = W

This is something from a practice sheet I got. I'm studying for a linear algebra final. I am unsure if we have to prove that $span(W) = W$ to do this proof.

My idea was to do a proof by contradiction like this:

If $span(W)$ is not equal to $W$, then there are some elements in $span(W)$ that are not in $W$ which means $W$ isn't closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition and therefore it is not a subspace.

Can someone push me in the right direction please.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made pretty much the key observation, so you've shown that

$$W \ne \operatorname{Span} W \implies W \text{ not subspace}$$

Taking the (equivalent) contrapositive, this gives

$$W \text{ subspace} \implies W = \operatorname{Span} W$$

(which could also be proven directly from the definition of subspace). For the other direction, you need to assume that $W = \operatorname{Span} W$, and use it to show that $W$ is a subspace (i.e. closed under addition and scalar multiplication); to do this, stare at the definition of span for a while.

Alternatively, you could again use the contrapositive and suppose $W$ isn't a subspace, and use it to conclude that $W \ne \operatorname{Span} W$.